# Forex trading algorithm implementation using Oanda issue

Tags: python, trading, forex

Hi I'm trying to implement a forex trading algorithm using the OANDA api. I created an account in OANDA and the key was generated.

What I tried was to implement the code in

http://jon.io/placing-your-first-forex-trade-with-python.html

I used the following code

```
import v20

api = v20.Context(
        'api-fxpractice.oanda.com',
        '443',
        token='HERE GOES YOUR API KEY')

response = api.order.market(
             'ACCOUNT ID',
             instrument='EUR_USD',
             units=5000)

print("Response: {} ({})".format(response.status, response.reason))
```

I'm getting the output as 'Response: 400 (Bad Request)'

I do not understand to create the conf file as explained in the post, given in the following github code.

[conf file creation](https://github.com/oanda/v20-python-samples)

Can someone kindly let me know the reason for this bad request output and the way to create the conf file.

Comment: Umm, i assume you put a token here: 'HERE GOES YOUR API KEY'

Comment: I correctly put the token at the code. Though it was not shown here :)

Comment: Yes you were correct friend. I have not put the account number .. thnk uuu